# Sed - Replace immediate next string/word coming after a particular pattern

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I'm a newbie to shell scripting and any help is much appreciated.

I have a pattern like this `rmd_ver=1.0.10`

I want to search the pattern `rmd_ver=` and replace the numeric part `1.0.10` with a new value in all the matches. Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 27):

To replace any value till the end of the line:

```
sed -i 's/\(rmd_ver=\)\(.*\)/\1R/' file
```

- `sed -i 's/p/r/' file` replace `p` with `r` in `file`
- `\(` start first group
- `rmd_ver=` search pattern
- `\)` end first group
- `\(` start second group
- `.*` any characters
- `\)` end second group
- `\1` back reference to the first group
- `R` replacement text

To replace the exact pattern in any place of the line and possibly several times in one line:

```
sed -i 's/\(rmd_ver=\)\(1\.0\.10\)/\1R/g' file
```

- `\.` escape special `.` into literal `.`
- `g` to replace multiple occurrences in one line

Comment: This is a great answer, since it is actually explains each regex pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you are too lazy to repeat the pattern in the replacement (`s/rmd_ver=1\.0\.10/rmd_ver=2.0.0/`), store it in a group:

```
sed -e 's/\(rmd_ver=\)1\.0\.10/\12.0.0/'
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description I think you just need the substitute command, with syntax `s/from_regex/to_result/`. To match a number like `1.0.10` you can match a repeat of digits or dot, e.g `[0-9.]`. That is a bit simple regex in that it will allow a dot at the start and the beginning, but let's start with that. Then your sed command becomes

```
sed 's/rmd_ver=[0-9.]\+/rmd_ver=42/' filename
```

The `+` is a repeat operator, and since sed is using BRE (basic regular expression) syntax it has to be escaped.

If you want to avoid matching dots on ends, like `1.2.3.`, you will have to change the regex to `[0-9][0-9.]\+[0-9]` to make sure that the first and last character is not a dot. Maybe you also want to be able to match a single digit, then you have to add an alternative (e.g. `/a|b/` matches a or b) to match that:

```
sed 's/rmd_ver=\([0-9][0-9.]\+[0-9]\|[0-9]\)/rmd_ver=42/' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\(rmd_ver=\).*[[:number:]]$/\1NEW_VAL/g'
```

you can replace NEW_VAL with the value you want to replace with.

Comment: This doesn't work because there is no class `[:number:]`. Maybe you meant `[:digit:]`, but even in this case it won't work as expected because `.*` matches to everything and the line can end with a non-digit. Also `g` has no effect here since you replace the whole line.