# BASH: changing a single variable in a line

Tags: bash, sed

Let's suppose a file contains the line:

```
PARAMETER = 10   # Comment ....
```

In a Bash script, I usually modify the PARAMETER value with

```
sed -i "s/PARAMETER = .*/PARAMETER = 20/" FILE
```

but this erases the comment afterward. Any suggestion for keeping it?

Comment: Match the digits only: `sed -i "s/PARAMETER = *[0-9]*/PARAMETER = 20/" FILE`. Can there be any float values? Anything else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed - Replace immediate next string/word coming after a particular pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22819608/3832970)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` means `any character, reapeated any amount of time`. By that logic, `#` falls in this category and will be captured.

To avoid that, the simplest technique is to use a negated character class, i.e. writting `any character that isn't in a set of specific chracters`

The syntax is `[^<any character you don't want>]`

You could write :

```
sed -i "s/PARAMETER = [^#]*/PARAMETER = 20 /" FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a match for any following comments.

```
sed -i "s/PARAMETER = [0-9]*\(.*\)/PARAMETER = 20 \1/" FILE
```

Comment: Use single quotes around scripts, not double (unless you have some reason to need to expose parts of the script to the shell, e.g. for variable expansion). If you just get rid of the `\(.*\)` from the regexp then you can also get rid of `\1` from the replacement text.